# How do I reference an array item by its index in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a JavaScript array:

```
Fruit > Banana > Colour > Yellow
               > Size   > Large
               > Cost   > $3.50
      > Apple  > Colour > Green
               > Size   > Small
               > Cost   > $0.42
```

I can get values using:

```
alert(Fruit['Banana']['Colour']);
```

**How do I get the same value using the indexes?** e.g.

```
alert(Fruit[0][0]);
```

Thank you everyone you lead me in the right direction, here is the solution I was after:

```
for (var a in Fruit) {
    //var a gives me "Banana" and "Apple"
    for (var b in Fruit[a]){
        //var b gives me "Colour", "Size" and "Cost"
        //Fruit[a][b] gives me the values
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for an associative Array?

Comment: I see you're using an object, but want to use indices as well. As @Edgar Villegas Alvarado mentions, this is not a native feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are confusing JavaScript [array objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure) with the fact that *all* objects are [associative arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array).  Note that normal objects (e.g. the "Fruit" object you allude to) do not have an intrinsic ordering of properties (keys) whereas Array objects do (due to the natural ordering of integral indices).  Essentially, an Array is just an object with a special "length" property that stores the last integer index (starting from zero) plus one.

Any object's properties will be iterated in *arbitrary* (e.g. random) order:

```js
var obj = {a:'Aye', b:'Bee', c:'See', d:'Dee'};
for (var prop in obj) {
  alert(prop + '=' + obj[prop]); // No order is guaranteed.
}
```

Strictly speaking, even arrays are not guaranteed by the specification to iterate in natural order using a `for-in` loop; however, most JavaScript interpreters do so anyway.  (Notably, IE8 iterates in the order that indices were assigned, not natural order.)  This is why you should always iterate arrays using indices in a plain "for" loop.

```js
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) { // i = [0 .. length-1]
  alert(arr + '=' + arr[i]); // Explicitly order as 'a', 'b', 'c'...
}
```

These differences mean that regardless of how your "Fruit" object is defined there is no reliable way to ensure a strict ordering of keys (e.g. "Banana", "Apple", "Color", "Size", etc.) unless you retain your own ordering separately.

Comment: Ok this is good, I can get "Colour", "Size" and "Cost" how do I then get their values also? like a for loop in a for loop or something?

Comment: @Craig: see my updated answer: try using `obj[prop]` where `prop` is the iterator variable in a `for...in` loop.

Comment: @maerics - the properties (numeric or otherwise) of arrays aren't ordered either. Arrays are just objects with a special *length* property.

Comment: @RobG: yes, that's true about Array objects and the ECMA-262 5th Edition specification states that the order of enumerated properties is not specified; however, in every JavaScript interpreter I've used, arrays will iterate in-order in a `for-in` loop.

Comment: @maerics—add array properties out of order in IE, then do a for..in loop. The are returned in the order they were added, not numeric (in IE < 9 at least).

Comment: @RobG: wow, just tested in IE8, you are absolutely right.  I'll think about how to update my answer in a useful way...

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little confused, because you seem to have answered your own question.  I also don't know how you have your array(s) set up.  But if you take a look at this example, you can see it working here:

http://jsfiddle.net/uyNnH/

This assumes that the top level array contains your fruit types and second level array contains each fruit type's properties.

**Update**:

From [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/User%3aquzi3/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Indexing_Object_Properties) and [others](http://www.nusphere.com/kb/jscoreguide/obj.html#Indexing%20Object%20Properties):

> In JavaScript 1.0, you can refer to an
>   object's properties by their property
>   name or by their ordinal index. In
>   JavaScript 1.1 or later, however, if
>   you initially define a property by its
>   name, you must always refer to it by
>   its name, and if you initially define
>   a property by an index, you must
>   always refer to it by its index.

So the issue is that you declare an associative array, instead of an indexed/ordinal-based one.  The only solution I can think of is using a (ugly) `for` loop.  Here's some un-tested pseudo-code:

```
function getItemByIndex(index, array) {
    var counter = 0;

    for (item in array)
    {
        if (counter == index)
        {
            return item;
        }

        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to be able to use both methods to get the values.
However the Fruit[0][0] does not work.

Comment: I see... there's no easy way to do it.. but I'll revise my answer.

Comment: I guess the array would look like:
Fruit = [Banana => [Colour => 'Yellow', Size => 'Large', Cost => '$3.50'], Apple=> [Colour => 'Green', Size => 'Small', Cost => '$0.42']];

Comment: @Kon mutating native objects should be discouraged. It can cause issues with other libraries (see PrototypeJs as an example of a troublesome library). Instead I'd suggest using wrappers or passing both the array and the sought attribute in, like Dojo and YUI.

Comment: @Josh, I agree.  I also was questioning that last point and actually removed it before seeing your comment. :)

Comment: @Josh - I'm neither a fan nor foe of Projotype, but I don't consider it a troublesome library given that, e.g., its messing with the native Array object is normally only a problem for bad client code...like when people are trying to use arrays as associative arrays, or doing `for in` loops without `hasOwnProperty()`, etc.

Comment: @nnnnnn I have to disagree. If you want a long prototype chain and need to iterate the props of something, including it's progenitors, then you want a naked `for in`, but because PrototypeJS mutates native Objects you can't reflect on inherited properties of objects that inherit from Arrays (among others). Because inheriting from Arrays can be really useful, PrototypeJS prevents us from doing useful things.

Answer (score 1):

You **can't**, *unless* you copy your string indexes to numeric indexes, but they would be new elements in your array

Answer (score 0):

You don't indicate how you create your array or assign those values, but it sounds like you don't know the difference between a JavaScript array and a JavaScript object.

An object has properties with keys that are strings, but you can't access those properties with an index integer, only by the key.

An array is a special type of object that provides array functionality like a `length` property and some methods like `sort()`, etc. Array properties are normally assigned with numeric indexes, and the `length` property is based on those numerically indexed properties, but because arrays are still objects you can also assign properties with string keys. If you say `myArray['banana'] = ..` that 'banana' property is not accessible via an index number.

If you want keys like 'banana' you shouldn't be using an array at all, just use a plain object.

There are plenty of articles explaining this in much more depth; here's one I found at random: http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/

Comment: I am creating the array in php (an array of arrays) and then using json_encode and sending it to javascript so I guess I have an object.

Comment: Ah. PHP arrays and JS arrays don't follow the same conventions.